# How to align spans in one line

Tags: python, html, css, django

Hello guys I have divs in a django template which are created by a Django for loop I have 2 spans in one div divided by a lot of whitespace, what I want to do is to align the second spans the spans with the tab class in one line , how do I accomplish this ?

I have tried adding padding, margin but it did not work

HTML:

```
<div>
     {% for entries in mylist %}
   <div class="ladder"> <span class="player"> {{ entries.0 }}</span> <span class="tab"> {{ entries.1 }} </span></div>
     {% endfor %}


</div>
```

CSS:

```
player { margin-left: 20px; 
    }

   .ladder{ width: 30%;
   border: solid 2px blue;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

   .tab { 

       margin-left: 40%;  }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/alGa7.png
I cant embed pictures right now so I got this link to show how it is right now, what I want is that the numbers are aligned in one line.

Comment: It looks like you are producing something that looks like a table? Have you considered using a table?

Comment: I dont want to use a table, I want to use this structure, it is exactly what I was looking for just have to align the numbers

Comment: specify the width of each span

Comment: @HenryM Like do a class give it a fixed with and give every span this class?

Comment: yes, via a class.  If you have a LHS (left hand side) class and a RHS (right hand sidE) class then they should line up vertically

Comment: I tried giving a fixed witdh but it did not change at all, can u exactly show like how I should do it? Should I add/delete lines from my css classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  background: #cc0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  background: #dd0
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

<dl>
  <dt>Mercury</dt>
  <dd>Ερμής</dd>
  <dt>Venus</dt>
  <dd>Αφροδίτη</dd>
  <dt>Earth</dt>
  <dd>Γη</dd>
</dl>
```